# jQuery .html something wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple code that I don't understand why it's not working.

So, some where in my html I have a table. And this  in it:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tx-right" colspan="2"><strong>Price</strong></td>
    <td class="td-speedy" id="speedy_price"></td>
    <td class="td-casting" id="casting_price"></td>
    <td class="td-search" id="snb_price"></td>
</tr>
```

Now this is my jQuery Code inside an ajax call:

```
if(typeof r.casting === 'undefined'){
    alert("a");
    ("#casting_price").html("<div class='alert'>Not available for this language and accent</div>");
    alert("d");
}
else
{
    alert("b");
    $("#casting_price").text("$"+ r.casting+" USD");
}
alert("c");
```

Ok now when the r.casting has a value on in it works fine and alerts: "b" and "c"
but when the r.casting is undefined nothing is printed and I get the "a" alert but nothing else!

What's going on here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo...

Comment: Did you check the console? My guess is that it tells the story.

Comment: `<td class="tx-right" colspan="2">` should probably be a `<th>` instead.

Comment: Well too much time looking at the code, it was a simple typo I'm very sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A missing dollar sign before `("#casting_price")`.

If you look at your console, you'll probably see a message similar to this:

> TypeError: "#casting_price".html is not a function

Comment: OMG please don't tell anyone hahah thx

Comment: Too late it's already on tomorrow's morning news :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
                $("#casting_price").html("<div class='alert'>Not available for this language and accent</div>");
```